# Get a GCD queue by name

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Is it possible to obtain the dispatch_queue_t of the GCD queue -- that has already been created -- by name.
I am dealing with code from a library the creates a queue with a name and I would like to dispatch_async tasks on it.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. Dispatch queue names are not unique, and are for debugging purposes only.